# Onload check radio button value and run function

Tags: javascript

I am trying run a function after local storage gets radio selection based on a value a, b , c, d so if a is check run switch statement one function if b run switch 22 ect..Is this possible??

```
<form>
<input type="number" name="abcd" id="abcd">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="a" onclick="example('one')">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="b" onclick="example('two')">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="c" onclick="example('three')">
</form>

<script>
function example(test) {
    var abcd = document.getElementById('abcd').value;
    switch (test) {
        case "one":
            exp_one = abcd + 5;
            break;
        case "two":
            exp_two = abcd + 10;
            break;
        case "three":
            exp_three = abcd + 15;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the localStorage part? Your snippet seems to be missing parts.

Comment: well im using garlic.js which does it automatically

Comment: could you please elaborate your problem.

Comment: i need to check the radios value so i can run the switch statement. The switch statement only works when an onclick event occurs so when the local storage re-gets the radio button the function is not calculated

Comment: please someone help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, the function is called onchange and you need it to be called also when you open the page.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   example("one"); 
   example("two"); 
   example("three"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lu7gnash/2/

It's not clear what's the pourpose of that, so I tried to make a reconstruction of the code and garlic.js (which I don't know). I assumed that exp_* variables are globals (otherwise your function is not doing anything).

Please, try to be more specific in future questions, it's really hard to tell what you want to archieve.